# trying to cast an object to javascript []{}- C# Key Value Collection OR Dictionary<string,object> or<string, string>

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i'd like to better understand the issue of casting object to a name vs value collection

say ...just if i could do it like that

**1)** does the java-script needs some fine tuning ? packing the data..

**2)** and most important for me : What is the correct  way to do the conversion from that key value `Js` to a `Dictionary<T,T> C#` ?

the `Aspx / Html` part

```html
<input type="text" id="tbx_Name" value="Avi" />
<input type="text" id="tbx_City" value="TelAviv" />
<input type="text" id="tbx_Country" value="Israel" />

<select id="ChosenRandomClass" style="display:none">
<option selected="selected" value="0">(choose a random)</option>
<option value="1">random Top Beach</option>
<option value="2">random Top Center</option>
<option value="3">random Local Pub</option>
</select>
```

the `JavaScript / jQuery` part

```javascript
  function AddNew() {

        if (!confirm("would you like to add this contact ?")) return;

        var Name = $('#tbx_Name').val();
        var City = $('#tbx_City').val();
        var Country = $('#tbx_Country').val();

        var selectedRC = $('#ChosenRandomClass option:selected').val();

        var hDate = []

        var param1 = { key: "Name", value: Name };
        var param2 = { key: "City", value: City };
        var param3 = { key: "Country", value: Country };
        var param4 = { key: "SelctedClass", value: selectedRC };

        hDate.push(param1);
        hDate.push(param2);
        hDate.push(param3);
        hDate.push(param4);
                                         // is this part necessary the data will not get to
                                         // code behind properly without the serializing ?
        var startPrt = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(hDate);
              ajaxUpdate("addNew", startPrt);

    }
```

the `Code behind C#` part

```C#
public void AddNewRecord(object startPrt)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> SenthDate = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   //        .....etc

}
```

i will appreciate the correct answer

thanks for your kind help and time.

Comment: What is the type of the **sent_hDate** object you're receiving in the C# method? Isn't it a **Dictionary(string, object)** already?

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena
i havn't even cheked it (:

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena
i am stuck right there in `AddNewRecord()` , population of `SentDate` could you be kind and plz Post  a little sample code so i could learn the right syntax on the dictionary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave your sample a try and noticed that the **startPrt** parameter is actually being received as an **Array** of **Dictionary(string, object)**. Hence, if you make the AJAX call like this:

```
var hDate = [];
hDate.push({ key: "Name", value: Name });
hDate.push({ key: "City", value: City });
hDate.push({ key: "Country", value: Country });
hDate.push({ key: "SelctedClass", value: selectedRC });

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: 'MyPage.aspx/AddNewRecord',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ startPrt: hDate }),
    success: success, // success callback
    error: error // error callback
});
```

You can define your **WebMethod** like the follwoing to convert the **startPrt** parameter to a dictionary:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void AddNewRecord(object startPrt)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (Dictionary<string, object> pair in (Array)startPrt)
        dict.Add((string)pair["key"], pair["value"]);
}
```

Comment: You are simply an angel ! to take my code and trying to find a work around ! thank you so very much i will give it a test , if you have another version as an upgrade to my idea with your experience and some more playing around ....i will be glad to see it here , hopefully some other people might find it handy , thx a million mate !

Comment: I'm just glad I could help ;). By the way, I think if try out some AJAX call parameter variations you might get something better since it is being desserialized as a combination of **Arrays** and **Dictionaries**.

Comment: i'll need to study (Jquery & ajax). after i learned some of it's *greatness* like posting data without full refresh(much more than just that)...

Comment: as i was concentrated on C#, I though.. but i really love c# it is much easier to comprehend, though i cant loose those key features of jQuery+UI,javascript and ajax as i need to actually  develop a complete product by my self.. i cant just "choose" a side of interest or preference , i need to deliver.. i think it's natural you do suppose ..at least to know how. and C# is much more...civilized ..i would call it,  intelligence... organized so well , and powerful no matter where

Answer (score 0):

The conventional approach would be to construct a plain javascript object, which can be used by `jQuery.ajax(...)` without any pre-processing.

```
var hDate = {
    "Name": $('#tbx_Name').val(),
    "City": $('#tbx_City').val(),
    "Country": $('#tbx_Country').val(),
    "SelctedClass": $('#ChosenRandomClass').val()
};
ajaxUpdate("addNew", hDate);
```

In `ajaxUpdate()`, the ajax expression will be something like this :

```
function ajaxUpdate(action, data) {
    ...
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        data: data,
        ...
        success: function(){
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Thus the serialized data will made available to the server-side script of whatever flavour.

Comment: Thanks a lot , though, how ...if you could say , the important part is i need it in a Dictionary i just wanted to understand second part which is how to load this key pairs into a dict'

Comment: I'm assuming that's something that happens server-side in some language I don't understand.

Comment: thanks for your help though , i think in your level of experience it should be fun for you to have some C# coding in your hands it is quite easy although friends of mine which dislike Ms .. they are doing it php way ...

Comment: Yup, all my server-side scripting these days is in PHP. In the past, JSP, ASP (pre .net), SSI and a little Perl. I'm too long in the tooth to start learning new stuff now. 10 years ago maybe.